# What is the best way to store a few fields?

Tags: plugin-development, custom-field, database

I'm researching what it would take to develop a custom Wordpress plugin. The plugin is a pretty small one. We just need to persist 2 fields of integer information. It's a pretty basic progress bar with current progress (int) and goal (int).

Is there a simple way of storing that amount of information in Wordpress? Is there a simple API for storing things like this in the db? Or, should I just persist by writing to a basic xml or json file on disk?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's the relation of this information, will it be specific to a post or post type, a comment, is there some common type of data this will be associated with, or is this a one off use?

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to use the built-in [Options API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) to add info to the wp_options table.

**To add the option**:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option

**To read the option value**:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Options API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API).

```
add_option(    'option_name', $values );
update_option( 'option_name', $values );
get_option(    'option_name', $default_value );
delete_option( 'option_name' );
```

You can store non-scalar values here too, an array with two entries for example. Make sure to use a unique name for the option name, [prefix everything](http://nacin.com/2010/05/11/in-wordpress-prefix-everything/).